# How can I increase the size of, and pad, a python list?

Tags: python, list

Say I have this list:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

and I want:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
```

What is the best way of doing this?

My current method is to create a new list:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [[n]*4 for n in x]
```

This gives:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Which seems close but no cigar... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [n for n in x for _ in range(4)]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

`itertools.repeat` is indeed semantically cleaner, thanks, Steven:

```
from itertools import repeat
[repeated for value in x for repeated in repeat(value, 4)]
```

Comment: The simplicity of this is hard to beat (+1)

Comment: +1.  I like this one best, but if I were to use an itertools solution I'd use `itertools.repeat`:  `[n2 for n in x for n2 in repeat(n, 4)]`.

Comment: Another `itertools` solution: `list(chain(*izip(*repeat(x,4))))`, but now we are descending into something that's difficult to mentally parse.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski `chain.from_iterable()` will outperform `chain()` in this case(at least for lists of size 1000).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain()` or `chain.from_iterable()` to flatten a list of lists (`y` in your case) :

```
In [23]: lis=[1,2,3,4]

In [24]: from itertools import chain

In [31]: y = list(chain(*([n]*4 for n in lis)))

In [32]: y
Out[32]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Some performance comparisons:

```
In [25]: x=[1,2,3,4]*1000  #can't use more than 1000 due to limited RAM

In [26]: %timeit list(chain(*([n]*1000 for n in x)))
1 loops, best of 3: 196 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(([n]*1000 for n in x)))
1 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit [n for n in x for _ in xrange(1000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 388 ms per loop

#three more solutions;from @Steven Rumbalski 

In [28]: %timeit [repeated for value in x for repeated in repeat(value,1000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 344 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(izip(*repeat(x,1000))))
1 loops, best of 3: 204 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit list(chain(*izip(*repeat(x,1000))))
1 loops, best of 3: 238 ms per loop
```

Comment: +1 I wonder how the `reduce` function compares (as @nvlass' answer)?

Comment: @atomh33ls `reduce()` is very slow compared to these alternatives.

Comment: Note that these methods compare very differently on small lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `reduce`

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [[n]*4 for n in x])
```

Comment: I just found this: `reduce(list.__add__,y)` which seems to work also.

Comment: @atomh33ls indeed :) list.__add__ is what's called when using `+` in lists

Comment: `operator.add` is faster than lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would have done.

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = x*4
y.sort()
```

Easy and Neat.

Answer (score 0):

Easy method:

```
y = [n for n in x*4]
```

This will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`.

To put it in the order you wanted, you can do `x = sorted(x)` or `y = sorted([n for n in x*4])`.

This is similar to `y = sorted(x*4)`.

The best method is to do it how @Pavel Anossov stated:

```
y = [n for n in x for _ in range(4)]
```

This is best because it will work for any sequence whereas `sorted(x*4)` does not keep the order and only works for originally sorted lists.

Comment: Well, this is applicable only for sorted lists. Does solve this particular solution indeed, but isn't universal and thus not reusable, which makes it pretty useless.